# WPF-button show msg of bootmode

Tags: wpf, vb.net, detect, boot

I have a `WPF` project with a simple `button` that when click will show the user what boot mode they are in.

I have found some code from Microsoft's website, but it may out of date? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291664

Here is my code:

```
Class MainWindow


 Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Const SM_CLEANBOOT& = 67
    Private Sub DetectModeButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles DetectModeButton.Click
    Dim result As Long

    result = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CLEANBOOT)

    Select Case result
        Case 0
            MsgBox("System started in normal mode.")
        Case 1
            MsgBox("System started in safe mode.")
        Case 2
            MsgBox("System started in safe mode with networking.")
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Unknown value returned from GetSystemMetrics.")
    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting the following error during runtime:

```
A call to PInvoke function 'BootModeTest!BootModeTest.MainWindow
::GetSystemMetrics' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely 
because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the 
unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling 
convention and parameters of the PInvoke 
signature match the target unmanaged signature
```

Any one know how to resolve this?

Any insight on the same are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The signature is wrong, looks like the code from that page is incorrect.  Change it to:

```
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
```

(possibly related to running on a 32bit vs 64bit machine)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Yes you are correct above 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: No problem, it is always a little unsettling to copy paste code from the Microsoft website and end up with such a scary error =).